# Range-querying timestamps in Firestore (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently struggling with an issue querying date ranges in Firestore. I have a collection of 'Matches' that each store a timestamp. I need to check for matches between two timestamps of different hours on the same day, however, I wasn't able to successfully do so. This is the query I used:

```
    db.collection("matches")
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date",openDate.getTime())
            .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("date",closeDate.getTime())
```

This the date (timestamp) field in one of the match objects:

```
 June 10, 2018 at 2:00:00 PM UTC+3
```

I have this if statement with a log inside just to see if the query returns anything

```
 if (!task.getResult().isEmpty()) { Log.d("TAG","Message"; }
```

The log never shows. 
This is an image of the database - https://imgur.com/a/cm5ZAq9

(I don't have the rep to add images yet).

Comment: What's the problem when you run this code?

Comment: The query essentially doesn't work, it doesn't return anything despite the existence of matches that occur in that date range.

Comment: Please make sure your question contains the [minimal *complete* information needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What's missing is: the data your querying, the actual query you execute, and the code that processes the results (preferably something like just logging the results).

Comment: Please add your database structure. A screenshot will be very helpful.